# How to lazy load texts in a webpage

Tags: lazy-loading

I have a webpage which conatins more than ten thousand lines. It is difficult to load that page in mobile browsers. Is it possible to lazy load texts in that web page? I don't want to create multiple pages and split content to each page. I found a plugin [Jscroll](https://jscroll.com/#/). Is it suitable for it or any other alternative available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Lazy Scroll Loading Plugin could be able to help you a great deal. It's very easy to use yet useful jQuery plugin that makes your site load faster and saves bandwidth. Uses jQuery Lazy Scroll Loading Plugin to only load html element (image, text, div, etc...) when it's visible in the viewport.

Comment: You mean the plugin I mentioned above?

Comment: This one- https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Improve-Page-Load-Times-With-jQuery-Lazy-Scroll-Loading-Plugin.html

Comment: The one you mentioned sends multiple AJAX request on scroll and will have negative impact on performance. Your requirement is very specific as your content is text so there is no point sending multiple ajax request to fetch data for it. I suggest ready the implementation it's quite simple to impliment. URL- jqueryscript.net/loading/…